# Standardize the full height and width of <input>, <select> and <button>

Tags: javascript, html, css, stylesheet

I'd like to standardize the full width and height (that is, the width and height *including* padding and border etc) in `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<button>` without losing the native styles that browsers use by default.

Is this possible? I'm open to using browser detection and JavaScript in addition to CSS.

Comment: @Close voters, could you point me to what this is the duplicate of? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
input, select, textarea, button{

    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

if you want the paddings and borders to eat from the width

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/WaxTS/222/

---

Use

```
input, select, textarea, button{
    -ms-box-sizing:content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:content-box;
    box-sizing:content-box;
}
```

if you want the paddings and border to be added to the width.

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/WaxTS/224/

***notice** for this case, buttons will not match the rest of the elements because they have different borders and if you mess with that, you disable the native look.*

Comment: But aren't borders of different widths and such on different platforms? This is a good step, of course but…

Comment: @luxum, yes but changing width and padding do not alter the native look.. Setting width and padding will make element the same in your page, and maintain the native look .. (*messing with the border disables the native look*)

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. The borders themselves, I believe, have different widths on each platform. I see how this could be remedied with the first option, but not the second.

Comment: @Luxun, you might be correct in that.. I am not sure about the different widths per platform, but if there is a difference then indeed the second option has that limitation.. That is the reason i mentioned the *notice*. (*i though only buttons would suffer from this, but i was just guessing/hoping..*)